# Paymill request error

Tags: api, paymill, incapsula

Calling Paymill API endpoints returns me an error HTML instead

`<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=19&xinfo=7-116343066-0 NNNN RT(1460904871089 46) q(0 0 -1 -1) r(150 -1) b6 U5&incident_id=198001240411479290-1000198536362854343&edet=20&cinfo=ffffffff1a40" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 198001240411479290-1000198536362854343</iframe></body></html>`

The example request could be this one (also tested several others with tha same result):

`curl -u PAYMILL_API_KEY:foo https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/client`

The weird thing is with three machines with Debian the above request fails miserably. With Ubuntu it does work. Have anyone experienced this?

Comment: Maybe curl is sending a weird user agent in Debian? You could try overriding it and seeing what happens

Comment: Tried `curl -A "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"`, the same result. What is curious is that this same request worked until today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an error on the Paymill side.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because Incapsula's CDN proxy failed to receive a response from the origin web server.

Ofer